# django: how to do calculation inside the template html page?

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I am using thumbnail plugin to get the image's width and height, now I want to define the padding of the img tag using the gotten height from thumbnail plugin, like:

```
<img style="padding-top: {{ img.height / 2 }}" src=""/>
```

But I got error here, does django not allow calculate like this?

Comment: can you please help me with my counting question I posted?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You need to use filters, like the `add` one which is built in:

```
{{ img.height|add:1 }}
```

The `div` is not, however; you can implement it yourself, though:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def div( value, arg ):
    '''
    Divides the value; argument is the divisor.
    Returns empty string on any error.
    '''
    try:
        value = int( value )
        arg = int( arg )
        if arg: return value / arg
    except: pass
    return ''
```

The usage would be similar, i.e.:

```
{{ img.height|div:2 }}
```

Comment: can I use divide and minus build-in filter?

Comment: Do such filters exist? The documentation ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/ ) doesn't list them, which is the reason I recommended writing your own.

Comment: This kind of thing is not going to be added to the built in filters: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/361

Comment: I really hate the try/except: pass statements.  I guess it depends on your data that's being passed to the div but I feel it's better to have the exception so if an engineer makes and error you at least know about it rather than get a return value of ''

Comment: And cant it also be rounded. For example `7/3`?

Answer (score 10):

There's a Python package that provides basic maths for Django templates: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters

With this, you can do it:

```
{% load mathfilters %}
<img style="padding-top: {{ img.height|div:2 }}" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 5):

For CSS like in your example you could use calc().

```
<img style="padding-top: calc({{ img.height }} / 2)" src=""/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just *have* to do it in the template. The following [DjangoSnippet](http://djangosnippets.org/) works great. Although you can abuse it, there are times when it Makes Life Simpler®.

[ExprTag - Calculating python expression and saving the result to a variable](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/9/)

Note: Not tested in 1.3, but works fine with anything before that.

Comment: Works fine with Django 1.8, but I had to tweak the exception expressions to bring them into line with Python3.

Comment: @Bobble: can you share the diffs? If you just want to email them to me, my addr is in my [Network Profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/9256/peter-rowell). Thanks.