# django: how to use django mathfilters in CSS or style HTML tags

Tags: css, django, django-template-filters

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848967/django-how-to-do-calculation-inside-the-template-html-page/), a user suggested this:

> For CSS like in your example you could use calc().
>
> ```
> <img style="padding-top: calc({{ img.height }} / 2)" src=""/>
> ```

I haven't been able to find anything similar to this using "calc", but I've tried it and it doesn't work for me. Is this the way to do it? Or is there another way to achieve this using django on CSS?

I'm trying to achieve something like the following, to create a "progress bar". So I'll have a total and then other values lower than this total and do a simple calc by the rule of three.

> ```
> <div style="width: calc({{ value1 }} * 100 / {{ total }})%">
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this like this:

You can calculate the value in your view:

```
def your_view(request):
    context = {"percent": 50}
    return render(request, 'your_view.html', context)
```

Then in your template (I used a div for example):

```
<div  style="height: 10vh; background-color: red; width: {{percent}}%"></div>
```